# generate data class from XSD to use between wcf service and client?

Tags: xml, wcf, xsd

I have used xsd.exe tool to generate data class but wcf doesn't like the data class to be exchanged and throws an error

**"There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:orderItems. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Store.Schemas.Order' with data contract name 'Order:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Store.Schemas' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
"**

There are a lot of classes that comes based of XSD. As per MSDN , it says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512.aspx , every data classes to be decorated with KnownTypeAttribute,DataContractAttribute, DataMemberAttribute etc.

**Is there a way where I can generate data class from xsd that can be used with WCF service? because changing the class generated by XSD.exe is not recommended nor easy process.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/ open source generator solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

i guess the first question is that do you have the wsdl as well which is referring the xsd. if yes then you can use the scvutil.exe and pass the wsdl path and make sure that the xsd files are also in same directory as wsdl file. this will generate the required data classes for you.

HTH

Comment: can you please paste the sample syntax?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\svcutil.exe" /t:code *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#

Comment: You can get the WSDL from appending ?wsdl to the service (svc) url. once u get that, u save a copy of that in the same location as your xsd files. then goto visual studio and do add service reference and give the path of your WSDL file in the service URL. if the xsd match in the WSDL then you should have ur data classes genererated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate classes using XSD.exe you will get XML serializable data type marked with all these Xml attributes conrolling its serialisation by `XmlSerializer`. Wcf by default uses `DataContractSerializer` which doesn't use those attributes used to describe serialization. You must switch to `XmlSerializer` by using `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute on your service, operation or service contract.

Comment: @rauts ...I didnt' get what you mean by wsdl ? I have the service running on IIS. Can you copy sample syntax for SVCutil.exe that takes xsd file and as well as service url

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka.... I tried wrapping the interface with [ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, 
    Use = OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
 and it didn't work and still complains of some classes in the xsd file

Comment: @Ladislav mrnka ...I just got xsd's from a client who were using xml serilaizer and it works if I generate data classes and use XmlSerializer deserlizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof()); but only in the service it doesn't work

Comment: But that is not how services works. To call a service XSD is not enough. You need WSDL which describes service's operation. XSDs are only referenced from WSDL.

Comment: @Ladislav mrnka I have a service wsdl and service contract operations everything. The data class that is being used as parameter in one of the operations is blowing because the data class is being generated by XSD.exe which doesn't datacontract and data member attributes

Comment: If you have wsdl use svcutil.exe instead of xsd.exe to generate both service client and data classes.